# High lumen recessed lights not available for some reason?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

For some reason there seems to be no availability of 1600 lumen recessed lights. 1600 lumens is about the output of a 100W incandescent lightbulb.

There are a few RS40 lights I found, but RS30 1600 lumen cannot be found, and I talked to an electrician and he said as far as he could see there no 1600 lumen retrofit recessed lighting systems at all.

This seems really strange to me. Am I missing something or is there some kind of weird regulation in the United States that is banning recessed lights over a certain brightness?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127526/discussion-on-question-by-tyler-durden-high-lumen-recessed-lights-not-available).

Answer (score 1):

I have purchased as high as 26W (250W equiv) LED PAR bulbs that could fit in a traditional high hat eg https://amzn.to/2VDcynA.

I have seen as high as 18W (150W equiv) LED pancakes eg https://amzn.to/3yU489D and https://amzn.to/3yTOQ4N

I suspect the reason there are not more high-powered recessed fixtures is lack of demand.  As noted in a comment, design with recessed lights would tend to call for more of them at lower power, and design for high powered lights would tend to call for other designs, IMO for fixtures that have more prominence.

That doesn't mean there is no call for hight powered recessed LEDs, just that nobody has made it a priority to make them yet.   Every year I find new kinds of LED products that I always wish I had.  What you want, 18W, does exist.  Give it a year and there will be more, and probably will be 21W ones too.

Links are not recommendations, just illustrations of the existence of uncommon products.   I should also note that some of the linked products are off-brand imports that may not be approved for use in the USA and may in fact not be safe.

Comment: I don’t think it is demand, but the 75 energy conservation act. I know I won’t buy 60w equivalent led’ but do get 100w, I never liked the limit and just added more fixtures until higher wattage LED’s became available.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a result of the 1975 energy policy and conversation act. There are some exceptions but the standard was 60w back then.

There are some exceptions per a 2010 petition to allow higher wattage and the restriction excluded the r20 short lamps but mfg’s were already making lower wattage/ luminance lamps so higher output values although not a fire hazard in led are much harder to find because the manufacturers were using the old standard.